# Semantic difference between "engine" and "motor"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Is there a semantic difference between *engine* and *motor*? In some cases, would the use of one or the other word be technically incorrect?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I like the definitions provided by [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) and their definition is the way I've understood the difference:

> - A [*motor*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=motor) is a machine that converts other forms of energy into mechanical energy and so imparts motion.
> - An [*engine*](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=engine) is a motor that converts thermal energy to mechanical work.
>
> *wordnetweb.princeton.edu*

So an *engine* is a specific type of *motor*. That's why it's not incorrect to speak of a motorboat, or a motorcar, or a motor speedway, even if the boat or car is clearly powered by combustion.

Note that if there's no combustion, there's no *engine*. Purely electric cars don't have engines.

As nouns, *motor* can also refer to a nonspecific agent that causes motion: "happiness is the aim of all men and the motor of all action", and *engine* can refer to something used to achieve a purpose: "an *engine* of change", a railway locomotive, or a machine used in warfare: "medieval *engines* of war".

Comment: I like this one the best so far, but [solid rocket motor](http://www.nasa.gov/returntoflight/system/system_SRB.html) confuses this answer, is this the exception to this rule?

Comment: @Jarrod I'm confused, exception in what way? All engines are motors…

Answer (score 4):

I picked the relevant parts from my dictionary and would say that these terms have been (over)used **figurative**.

Googles services are called a search-engine but never would be called a search-motor. In the field of software development we talk about graphic-engines, physical-engines etc.  but never about motors.

> motor |ˈmōtər| noun a machine, esp. one powered by electricity or
>   internal combustion, that supplies motive power for a vehicle or for
>   some other device with moving parts. • a source of power, energy, or
>   motive force : **hormones are the motor of the sexual functions**.
>
> engine |ˈenjən| noun a machine with moving parts that converts power
>   into motion. • a thing that is the agent or instrument of a particular
>   process : **exports used to be the engine of growth**.

Answer (score 3):

In a strictly physics sense an **engine** converts energy into mechanical work.
A **motor** is a subset of engines that produce motion as the mechanical work.
So all motors are engines but not all engines are motors.

Sometimes they are used interchangeable eg. rocket engine and rocket motor.
Motor is generally used for electrical devices but it's also used as an abbreviation for motorized eg. motorboat or motorcycle.

Comment: Interesting that WordNet reverses the set inclusion: an engine is a type of motor. I suppose it depends on your point of view: all mechanical work is motion, strictly speaking.

Comment: @ghoppe - motive is probably a better word.

Comment: There's a motor in my electric fan, but I wouldn't say it has an engine.

Comment: @ghoppe you may need mechanical work just to remain in place. Think of an airplane flying against the wind

Comment: Its actually the opposite. The engine is a subset of motor. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The real difference, is the fact that "motors" run on electricity, while "engines" run on combustion. However, many people interchange the [usage of these words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/engine.htm):

> On the rare occasions we encounter one, we refer to a steam locomotive as an engine, the same word that we give to the motive power of an aircraft. But all electrical devices are driven by motors. In Britain at least, one’s personal transport is a motor car (with compounds such as motor trade, motor vehicle and motor sport), even though it’s always powered by an engine. Small boats may have outboard motors and then are often called motor boats.

From a [mechanic:](http://www.bicyclesports.us/what_s_the_difference_between_an_engine_and_a_motor_.htm)

> So, what is the difference between an engine and a motor?
>        Motors are electric.  Electricity powers motors.
>        Engines are powered by come sort of pressure or combustion, ie: steam  engines, automobile engines, diesel engines.
>        Pretty simple, really.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson (In extension of Thursagen's answer) Also, the word "engine" can be used in a more abstract fashion. A good way to look at it is an engine is the primary work horse (instigator of work or progress) for a particular entity.

Comment: Then why are race tracks called `Motor Speedways` instead of `Engine Speedways`? This goes back at least 100 years, ie. Indianapolis Motor Speedway. Is this the same as the classic `Driveway` vs `Parkway` dichotomy?

Comment: As I said, a lot of people do not know the difference, hence the usage has been pretty mix up. But *technically* there should be a difference

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson Motors have been around since about mid 1800's. Some of the first vehicles were electrically driven, so I'm assuming the speedway was first taken from those.

Comment: To make things more confusing, large reusable software projects are often referred to as 'engines' - i.e, a physics engine, game engine, or search engine.

Comment: And they dom't run on combustion

Comment: @Hannele I would say that's a different definition of the word, the "something used to achieve a purpose" definition.

Comment: At first I agreed with this definition, but upon reflection it's incomplete and confusing. People don't refer to "motorboats" or "Motor speedways" because they're mixed up or the first vehicles were electric. It's true that engines rely on combustion, or more generally, heat conversion; but motors are not always electric. Otherwise "electric motor" would be a redundant phrase. An engine is a specific type of motor. See my answer.

Comment: This is nonsense.

Comment: Here is an example of NASA referring to a rocket motor: clearly a combustion-based device ( http://www.nasa.gov/returntoflight/system/system_SRB.html )

Comment: @Thursagen In my 25 years of software development I have seen lots of software that is combustible ;-)

Comment: General Motors is the largest gasoline engine car company in the world.  Because Detroit had so many gasoline car companies, it was referred to as the motor city.  Clearly the definitional claim made here has NOTHING to do with reality.